# The import java.sql.DriverManager cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, mysql-connector, webdriver-manager

You can see that there is an error when importing the java.sql.DriverManager package:
[image]

You can see in the left part of the next picture, which jar file called mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar is installed.
But the error is still happening: "The import java.sql.DriverManager cannot be resolved":
[image]

Please can anyone help solve this little problem?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why aren't you using Maven or Gradle to manage your dependencies?

Comment: DriverManager is a core Java SE class, and it has been present since JDK 1.2  So I suspect there is something wrong with your Eclipse project settings.

Comment: Is the mylsq-connector jar present in `lib` a part of classpath? Extend the Libraries section and see if the jar is there. Otherwise, you can right click on the jar add to the classpath.

Comment: Side note:  Class.forName hasn’t been needed for JDBC operations since Java 1.6.

Comment: Hello, Yogesh Badke! Thank you very much! Because of you answer, I fixed this problem!
Eclipse -> Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variables -> New -> Write the name of the needed file -> Write the path of the needed file -> OK -> Apply and Close.

Thank you very much! You are Excellent! :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed problem:
Eclipse -> Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variables
-> New ->Write the name of the needed file -> Write the path of the needed file -> OK -> Apply and Close.